# The SSL connection could not be established. Authentication failed

Tags: c#, rest, ssl, post, https

I got an error of "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Authentication failed, see inner exception." when trying to POST request over SSL via C# HttpWebRequest(have tried RestSharp and HttpClient the result is the same). I also tried all the possible resolutions mentioned on the web, like:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            { return true; };
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

None of them worked for me. The other issue is that I run the same project on another computer, and it works without any problem. So it looks like that the problem source is the environment, maybe some settings in the .net framework or regedit should be changed. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you use a client certificate? If so, make sure the executing user has permission to read the certificate.

Comment: No, there is no client certificate.

Comment: After all this time, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to TLS version (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netcore-3.1) more information about security protocol types).
An idea is to try using more security protocol types and in case it's working, you can check which protocol you can use:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            { return true; };
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

Comment: I have tried all of them even SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3, unfortunately, it didn't help. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can try to see which SSL/TLS protocol is set in registry. (see this link https://community.progress.com/s/article/How-to-modify-SSL-TLS-settings-from-the-registry). Maybe you need to change the value in registry, use the same protocol in code and try again.

Comment: Tried some manipulations with regedit Shannel directory, but nothing changed.

Comment: I faced a similar issue with the TLS version and shared my learnings in [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713290/1205339).