# The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, .net-6.0

I need to download a document from url but I'm getting SSL connection error,
I have tried all the solutions shared on stack overflow, which were almost the same but I'm still getting this error,
AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.

```
public async Task<ClientResult<HttpResponseMessage>> GetDocumentData(string url)
            {
                var getDocumentDataResult = new ClientResult<HttpResponseMessage>();

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                try
                {
                    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
                    {

                    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

                        //Setting TLS 1.2 protocol
                        httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;

                    var certFile = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents", "31075939.cer");
                    httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile));
                    certFile = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents", "30955730.cer");
                    httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile));


                        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

                        //var stream = new FileStream(url, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        Uri absoluteUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

                        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(absoluteUri);

                        Byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                        //result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

                        getDocumentDataResult.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                        getDocumentDataResult.ResultContent = bytes.ToString();

                    }
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    getDocumentDataResult.ExceptionText = ex.Message;
                    getDocumentDataResult.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                }
                return getDocumentDataResult;
            }
    }
}
```

Complete Error is,

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)

Comment: This code isn't enabling TLS1.2, it's *disabling* validation and enabling the insecure TLS1.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have updated code to only enable 1.2, and yes validation was disabled but it still gives the error.
Although the code to enable validation was just added but commented out, the error is still there. If you could guide me in the right direction

Comment: You don't have to do anything at all to enable TLS1.2. .NET Core, in all supported Windows versions, uses the best available option - TLS1.3 or TLS1.2. You don't need to specify a client certificate either, unless the server requires it. All you need to do to use HTTPS is to just use an HTTPS URL. If you *do* use a client certificate though, it needs to be a valid one. Have you tried just using HttpClient directly? `var client=new HttpClient(); var bytes=await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);` is all you need to retrieve something over HTTPS

Comment: Yes, I commented all of the code regarding certification and enabling of TLS, but the SSL error is still there.
I think the certificate is required by the server.

Comment: Why do you think that? You can't just add any certificate. If the server uses certificate authentication, it wants a very specific certificate it recognizes. In that case, the docs or admin would make that explicit. Have you tried just downloading the file without any modifications?

Comment: What's the actual full exception text? The message alone isn't enough. Log and post the full string returned by `Exception.ToString()`. It may contain additional information in any inner exceptions. You simply can't fix certificate or version errors at the HttpClient level. What OS are the client and server running? If one of them runs an unsupported version of Windows you'll have to patch to enable TLS1.2+.

Comment: The above certificates were provided for this issue and those are the names of the exported certificates.
Windows, .net6 is used by the client.
no information was provided for the server's OS and framework version.

Comment: Was that the *only* information? If you google the error message you'll see it's often caused because the server and client [can't agree in a common cipher algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223539/ssl-error-the-message-received-was-unexpected-or-badly-formatted-for-a-net-ap) - not TLS1.2 but the algorithms TLS1.2 will use. That's why the OS version matters. You may have to patch the server or client\

Comment: If you browse to that URL the certificate icon to the left of the address bar will contain information about the certificate and the algorithms it uses.